# Proving $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \sin(x) + x$ is surjective

Tags: functions, trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing

## Attempt

**Claim:** $f(x) = \sin(x) + x$ is surjective.

*Proof:* Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \sin(x) + x$.

Now, $I = [i,i+1]$, where $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Define the restriction $f|_I: I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $(f|_I)(x) = f(x)$.

Because $f$ is continuous everywhere, $f|_I$ is continuous on $I$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, for each $y \in [\min(f(i),f(i+1)), \max(f(i),f(i+1))]$, there exists $c \in (i,i+1)$ such that $f(c)=y$. This means that $f|_I$ is surjective on $I$.

Hence, $f$ is surjective on $$\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} [i,i+1] = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} [i, i+1) = \mathbb{R}$$

**Q.E.D.**

## Questions:

Does the proof have errors? If there are no errors, is it valid? It seems good because I proved that the restriction is surjective on every interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

## Edit (making corrections)

Correction:

Because $f$ is continuous everywhere, $f|_I$ is continuous on $I$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, for each $y \in [\min(f|_I(i),f|_I(i+1)), \max(f|_I(i),f|_I(i+1))]$, there exists $c \in (i,i+1)$ such that $f|_I(c)=y$. This means that $f|_I$ is surjective on $I$.

Comment: $f|_{I}(x) = \sin(x) + x$ is not surjective onto $\mathbb{R}$. You only showed it is surjective onto some $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: But, if its not surjective, then what real number $y$ is not mapped from any $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For $x \in I = [a, b]$, $f(x) \leq 1 + x \leq 1 + a$ and $f(x) \geq - 1 + x \geq b - 1$. So $f(I) \subset [b - 1, a + 1]$. So $f(I)$ is always a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think I made a typo on my proof. I think I will write an edit. Thanks, @Mason.

Comment: @Mason, is that better? (See edit)

Comment: You have shown that $f(\mathbb{R}) \supset \bigcup_{i = -\infty}^{\infty}[\min(f|_I(i),f|_I(i+1)), \max(f|_I(i),f|_I(i+1))]$. This does not imply that $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Being surjective is not a local property of a domain. You can do this trick with the continuity, but not with the surjectivity.

Comment: Use darboux property of continuous map.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) & = \lim_{x\to\infty}(\sin(x) + x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + 1\right) = +\infty
\end{align*}

Similarly, one has that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sin(x) + x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}x\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + 1\right) = -\infty
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?